# What happens to Ant Man in the Kosmos dimension?

Tags: marvel, comics, ant-man

Ant Man gets small because Pym particles shunt his matter into the [Kosmos dimension](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kosmos_(dimension)).

**What happens in the Kosmos dimension when almost all of Ant Man's matter suddenly appears there?**  Is there any documentation of unintended side effects?  Given that the Kosmosians hate humanity, is Ant Man's matter at risk there?